# how do i create batch file with file name and move the file to same directory

Tags: batch-file

I have many file with mpg format. I want make a batch file for create  directories
with mpg file name and move the mpg file to same directory .

Comment: What did you tried as code ? you should show us your tries and explain where are you stuck on ?
Take a look at this ==> http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: it is unclear what you want. please try to get to the solution yourself first (search online, follow bash scripting tutorials, try out some code), and then come back here if you have a specific problem with it. tips: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /aa /b *.mpg') do (
  md "%%~na"
  move "%%a" "%%~na"
)
pause
```